# TS2551: Property 'post' does not exist on type 'PostListComponent'

Tags: angular, typescript

I've read answers but I'm stuck... I'm trying to remove a post with the action of a click. I've created all the methods but I have this error in my post-list-component.html when I add post as argument on the onDeletePost() method : TS2551: Property 'post' does not exist on type 'PostListComponent'. Did you mean 'posts'? And if I put posts I've another error message(TS2345)...
Let me know if you need more informations, thank you very much !!

Here is my **posts.service.ts** :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Post } from '../models/post.model';

@Injectable()
export class PostsService {


  posts : Post[] = [];
  postsSubject = new Subject<any[]>();

  emitPosts() {
      this.postsSubject.next(this.posts);
    }

  createNewPost(newPost : Post) {
    this.posts.push(newPost);
    this.emitPosts();
  }

  removePost(post : Post) {
    const postIndexToRemove = this.posts.findIndex(
      (postEl) => {
        if(postEl === post) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return ' '
        }
      }
    );
    this.posts.splice(postIndexToRemove, 1);
    this.emitPosts();
  }
}
```

**post-list-component.ts** :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Post } from '../models/post.model';
import { PostsService } from '../services/posts.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-list',
  templateUrl: './post-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-list.component.scss']
})
export class PostListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  
  posts : Post[];
  postsSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private postsService: PostsService,
              private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.postsSubscription = this.postsService.postsSubject.subscribe(
      (posts: Post[]) => {
        this.posts = posts;
      }
    );
    this.postsService.emitPosts()
  }


  onDeletePost(post: Post) {
    this.postsService.removePost(post);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.postsSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

and my **post-list-component.html :**

```
<li class="list-group-item">
  <button class="btn btn-warning" (click)="onDeletePost(post)"> Supprimer </button>
</li>
```

Comment: So, what is `post` that you want to pass to the delete? Where is it defined? Supposedly it should be a template variable, but your html-snippet doesn't show any of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be in your html, as watching your snippet. I would change the html code to

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let post of posts">
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <button class="btn btn-warning" (click)="onDeletePost(post)"> Supprimer </button>
    </li>
</ng-container>
```

> What caused the error?

Basically you have an array of `posts` that you want to be displayed in your page. In order to do that, you need to cycle that array post per post.

```
*ngFor="let post of posts"
```

Does that, creating a reference of a `post` for each iteration.

So for Example if you have the posts's array having 3 post, the `ngFor` will cycle that array three times.

Inside the ngFor you can now pass `post` to the function `onDeletePost`.

More about *ngFor [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-ngfor/)

Comment: Ah yes thank you it works, I don't have any error message now ! Can you explain it to me ? Or I'll try to find an answer by myself ! :) thank you

Comment: Sure, I'll edit my answer